# Image gallery control for ASP.Net with filtering capabilities

Tags: asp.net, database, image, controls, thumbnails

I'm writing an ASP.Net application which needs to display a large number of thumbnails, preferably in a paginated format.  These thumbnails will be stored on the server's hard disk, but will have their filenames listed in a SQL Server database.  What I want to do is to be able to filter the images being displayed based on criteria within the database.

I've looked at the [NotesForGallery](http://notesforgallery.codeplex.com/) control, which I really like, but it doesn't seem to have a way to do that. --if I'm wrong, please correct me.

Are there any other image gallery type controls, preferably free, that can do what I need?  I'm hoping someone can recommend a control or solution that will point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you concerning with the filter part or the gallery part? I am not quite clear.

If your criteria are in the db, why don't you do a filter at querying the data, and then bind it to one of the data binding control?

Comment: I'm primarily interested in the filter part.  The filtering of filenames will be done with a query, but all the images are stored in the same directory.  The NotesForGallery control is nice, but it displays ALL images in the specified directory.  I need a control that can accept a list of filenames and only display those images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like K2so was saying, have you looked at just databinding to a simple repeater or datagrid? Since your image names and other properties are in the database, you could run your query and spit back out a list of images.

Example (rough code, sorry)

```
<asp:repeater id="yourImages" runat="server">
    <itemTemplate>
        <img src='~/Images/Files/<% Bind("ImageFileName")%>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:repeater>
```

Using a paginated grid view would be very similar as well.

EDIT:  I tried to post this as a comment, but the link wouldn't work very well.  Here is a demo of asp.net listView with images in a grid and paged.  [Matt Berseth Demo Site](http://mattberseth2.com/demo/Default.aspx?Name=Tag+Cloud+Filters+with+ASP.NET+3.5's+LinqDataSource+and+ListView+Controls&Filter=All)

Comment: Watch out for that /> unless your doctype is xhtml.

Comment: That's a possibility.  I'd like to be able to generate a 6x6 set of thumbnails.  Maybe a grid view would be the best bet.

Comment: Are you on .NET 3.5? If so, check out this article by Matt Berseth (whatever happened to him anyways...?) - it shows a paged listView with images as part of the demo - i updated my answer with the link, SO does not like some of the chars in it I think...

Comment: I ended up using the DataList control instead of a Repeater.  According to Microsoft, its essentially the big brother of the Repeater.  --So far, its working fairly well.  I'm still having some issues with paging, but I think they I can solve them.